# How to use a 4x4 matrix as a vertex attribute in GLSL?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, vertex-shader

I am trying to use a 4x4 matrix as a vertex attribute, using this code:

```
Mat4 matrices[numVerts];

int mtxBoneID = glGetAttribLocation(hProgram, "aMtxBone");

glEnableVertexAttribArray(mtxBoneID + 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(mtxBoneID + 1);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(mtxBoneID + 2);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(mtxBoneID + 3);
glVertexAttribPointer(mtxBoneID + 0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Mat4), ((Vec4*)matrices) + 0);
glVertexAttribPointer(mtxBoneID + 1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Mat4), ((Vec4*)matrices) + 1);
glVertexAttribPointer(mtxBoneID + 2, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Mat4), ((Vec4*)matrices) + 2);
glVertexAttribPointer(mtxBoneID + 3, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Mat4), ((Vec4*)matrices) + 3);

// shader:
// ...
attribute mat4 aMtxBone;
// ...
```

But all I get on the screen is garbage.

Comment: If you want to do mesh skinning, it's better to pass matrices as uniforms and deference them using one or more integer vector attribute(s).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I'm running into the exact same problem.

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355051/using-a-matrix-as-vertex-attribute-in-opengl3-core-profile

Comment: @sak Like Luca says, you can pass an integer index into an array as the vertex attribute, but instead of sending matrices in as uniforms(shaders have a max number of uniforms which may not be enough) you can store all your matrices in a floating point texture, then sample them using nearest-neighbour sampling.

Comment: What does the Mat4 type look like?

Answer (score 1):

So, my answer was deleted because of reasons unknown.

Here I go again, I'll format it differently this time.

I had the EXACT same problem as the question had/has, stuff would be drawn quite messed up. At least that's the description.

What fixed it for me was calling

```
glDrawElementsInstancedBaseVertex(GL_TRIANGLES,
                                    d->drawCount,
                                    GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
                                    0,
                                    p_objects.size(),
                                    0);
```

To draw my stuff, just this and nothing more.

HOWEVER!

This MIGHT not be the only issue you have if your stuff is drawn incorrectly. The entire list of stuff you NEED to get correct it immense. So i'm going to put a link here, which has a great tutorial on how to draw lots of stuff. Also, you can get the source code and try it out yourself.

http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial33/tutorial33.html

Sources here: http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/ogldev-source.zip

Downvote me again and delete my answer, it's content hasn't changed at all from what it was.

Ban me from the site, your loss.

Answer (score 0):

you may try something like this
in your shader use layout

```
layout(location=x) in mat4 <name>;
```

x won't be equal to `glGetAttribLocation`,you must maintain it by yourself.it is equal to number times you call `glVertexAttribPointer`.
example

```
layout(location=0) in vec4 in_Position;
layout(location=1) in vec4 in_Color;
layout(location=2) in vec4 in_Normal;

glVertexAttribPointer(0, xxxxxxxx);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, xxxxxx);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, xxxxxx);
```

Comment: It should be noted that the location index is not always 'equal' as stated above, since a single index is allocated for each pair of 4 vertices. Therefore, a matrix would contain 4 index locations (or 16 floats). If you attempt to store a matrix at location 0, and a vec4 at location 1, you will get an error after linking the shader because the two attributes cause an overlap. You would need to place the vec4 at location 4, or the mat4 after the vec4 to avoid such an error.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short OpenGL spec does not support what you want.

Vertex attribute format has a maximum of 4 components. So you are stuck with vec4 as the highest dimension input for a vertex attribute.

Cf OpenGL 4.6 specification, table 10.3, page 354.

If I were you I would store my matrices in a UBO / SSBO and consume them using gl_VertexID or a user defined index passed as a vertex attribute.

Edit:
Or you can do as in the linked SO post added in one of the comments [Using a matrix as vertex attribute in OpenGL3 Core Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355051/using-a-matrix-as-vertex-attribute-in-opengl3-core-profile): You consume 4 vertex attributes, each being a vec4. I find it ugly and harder to maintain but if you can measure a perf increase for your use case then do that.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to create VBO (`glGenBuffers`) for your matrix, then bind it (`glBindBuffer`) as current, then use

```
glVertexAttribPointer(mtxBoneID + 0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glVertexAttribPointer(mtxBoneID + 1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 4);
glVertexAttribPointer(mtxBoneID + 2, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 8);
glVertexAttribPointer(mtxBoneID + 3, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 12);
```

instead of your `glVertexAttribPointer` calls.

Comment: Vertex Buffer Objects are not mandatory. So, no, that's not the solution.

Comment: Updated my answer. But it seems that you're using OpenGL 2. I recommend switching to OpenGL 3, as it seems to be less buggy (I got some strange behaviour very often when using OpenGL 2, and OpenGL 3 doesn't have that problem).

Comment: Now the answer is completely obsolete, just presenting the code he already uses. There is only one difference and that difference makes your answer even **wrong**, since a stride of `12 * sizeof(float)` won't work. You need the bytes from the **start** of one vertex to the next, so most probably `16 * sizeof(float)` or, even better, `sizeof(Mat4)`. But wait, then it would be totally his code and you're ready to delete the answer.

Comment: @AntonGuryanov OpenGL 2 isn't in any way less buggy than OpenGL 3. The only thing that could be buggy is your implementation (hardware+driver) (you're not using an *ATI* or *Intel* GPU, are you?). It may be just that the cleaner and simpler interface of core OpenGL 3 gives drivers less chance to fail.

Comment: @ChristianRau oops, my bad. Then all I can suggest is to try VBO's with OpenGL 3, and the problem can dissappear. And about my GPU's, when I was using OpenGL 2, I had NVidia GPU, and I had some strange issues. Then I switched to OpenGL 3 and got a new computer with AMD Radeon. Since then, I didn't notice any bugs or strange behaviour.

Comment: Or maybe it's an issue with `Mat4`? Can you post your `Mat4` and `Vec4` classes?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your offsets are off.  It should be

```
((Vec4*)matrices) + sizeOf(Vec4)*i
```

instead of

```
((Vec4*)matrices) + i
```

Comment: This is wrong. When you add an integer to a pointer, the offset added is equal to the product of that integer and the size of the object in bytes. The code you provided is equivalent to->  ((char*)matrices) + (sizeof(Vec4) * i) * sizeof(Vec4)